# Install Tomcat 9.0.16 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat

I'm trying to install Java and Tomcat on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm following this guide:

https://noviello.it/come-installare-apache-tomcat-9-su-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

I've already done hundreds of attempts. Could I know what's wrong with the tutorial?
Do you know of the most recent and functional guides to install Tomcat 9.0.16 on Ubuntu 18.04?
I also tried this guide but without success:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-tomcat-9-ubuntu-1804

I would like to do exactly what I find in these two guides:

https://noviello.it/come-installare-apache-tomcat-9-su-ubuntu-18-04-lts/
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-tomcat-9-ubuntu-1804

This is what I would like to do:

```
sudo passwd root
******
sudo passwd ubuntu
******
su
******
apt-get update
apt update
apt install default-jdk
groupadd tomcat
useradd -s /bin/false -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat
cd /tmp
apt install curl
curl -O http://it.apache.contactlab.it/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.16/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.16.tar.gz
mkdir /opt/tomcat
tar xzvf apache-tomcat-9.0.16.tar.gz -C /opt/tomcat --strip-components=1
cd /opt/tomcat
chown -R tomcat:tomcat /opt/tomcat
chmod -R g+r /opt/tomcat/conf
chmod -R g+w /opt/tomcat/logs
chmod -R g+w /opt/tomcat/temp
chmod -R g+w /opt/tomcat/webapps
chmod -R g+w /opt/tomcat/work
usermod -a -G tomcat tomcat
update-java-alternatives -l
nano /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=network.target
[Service]
Type=forking
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'
ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start tomcat
systemctl status tomcat
ufw enable
ufw allow ssh
ufw default allow
ufw allow 80
reboot
su
******
apt-get update
ufw status
systemctl enable tomcat
nano /opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
<user username="******" password="******" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
nano /opt/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
nano /opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml
<!--<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />-->
systemctl restart tomcat
ls -R /opt/tomcat/conf/
nano /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
systemctl restart tomcat
http://IP-PUBBLICO-SERVER
```

Where is the error?
What are the tests I can do on the machine to understand what the problems are?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Steps look good.Except that you didn't install Java. Is java already installed and in PATH?

Follow these steps manually

Check the Java version in PC

1) Create user and group `tomcat`

2) Extract the tomcat .tar file in `/opt`

3) `chown tomcat:tomcat /opt/tomcat`

4) `chmod -r u+g rwx /opt/tomcat/*.sh`

5) start tomcat using `start.sh`

If every thing works add it in service.

Answer (score -1):

Just download the [Apache Tomcat distributable file](https://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.16/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.16.tar.gz) and extract it on your machine

Comment: The question is not so simple. You need to install java, create the Tomcat service. Furthermore there is the speech related to permits.